# Pip install fuzzy fails because gcc fails to compile

Tags: python, gcc, pip

I want to install fuzzy python package. I have windows 7 operating system with `mingw32` and `python 2.7`. When I try to pip install the fuzzy package, I get the following error.

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\src\fuzzy.o: bad reloc address 0x0 in section `.data'
    collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Here's the complete log.

Please please help!

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21566454/command-gcc-failed-with-exit-status-1

Comment: That's clearly a different error. I have already removed mnocygwin flags. Also my error reads something like bad reloc addres in section 'data'. Which isn't the case in the other question you have referred to.

Comment: Perhaps this will help: Try to run the setup.exe for Cygwin and select the gcc package(s), then make sure `gcc` points to gcc rather than to mingw32.

Comment: @TomStephens Can you please elaborate a little? Didn't get you

Comment: Did you get this resolved yet?  If not, post the output of `gcc --version` and say what else you've tried.  Also, google.

Comment: Not yet. I did what you suggested. Now I am getting a different error. Here it is.
 File "C:\Python27\Scripts\pip-script.py", line 9, in <module>
   load_entry_point('pip==1.5.4', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\__init__.py", line 185, in main
   return command.main(cmd_args)
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 161, in main
   text = '\n'.join(complete_log)
nicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 59: ordinal
not in range(128)

Comment: holy cow. I don't know what to tell you but it may just be that [`fuzzy` is waaaaay out of date](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Fuzzy) (and apparently no longer being developed?).  Can you use something other than `fuzzy`?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error when trying to install the (not part of anaconda) mmh3 module on an anaconda installation on windows.

It seems that **your path** includes an independent mingw installation (**c:/mingw/bin/**../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe)
 I had to remove my mingw from my path so that it used the **MiniGW that corresponds to your Python**, so try to check e.g. if

```
ld.exe -version
```

and

```
...\anaconda\MinGW\bin\ld.exe -version
```

give you the same, if not, make sure your path is correct as discussed above...